# Prove that there are only finite numbers satisfying this equation:

Tags: number-theory, inequality, recreational-mathematics

Coincidentally, I realized that my room number $(23)$ has the following property:

$$2^3+1=3^2$$

In order to find more numbers $n$ exhibiting this property, I wrote the following equation: $$(n-1)^n+1=n^{n-1}$$

Now, I realized that for $n>3$, where $n$ is an integer, the LHS becomes greater than the RHS and therefore if one shows that for $n>3$ the following inequality holds, it would prove that there are not infinite numbers that show this property.

Inequality: $(n-1)^n+1>n^{n-1}$

I am still a beginner in Inequalities and would, therefore, like to see as to how should one proceed further with this argument.

Comment: For the record, even the more general equation $x^a+1=y^b$ does not have other solutions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture

Answer (score 1):

$(n-1)^n+1\gt n^{n-1}$ can be rewritten as

$$\left(1-{1\over n}\right)^n\gt{1\over n}-{1\over n^n}$$

Does the left hand side look familiar?

Comment: Does it have to with the definition of e?

Comment: If n->infinity then LHS will become $1\over e$ and the RHS will become zero.

Comment: @ShreyAryan, it does indeed!

Comment: @ShreyAryan, it's also possible to show by induction that $(1-1/n)^n\gt1/n$ for $n\gt3$, without invoking the relationship with $e$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other solution than that which is given; 
first observe that $n$ must be odd otherwise the $+1$ will not cancel, expanding as binomial; $[-1+n(n-1)/2-...+n^n  +1]=n^{n-1}$ from here you notice that for the equation to hold for any odd $n>3$, then $n|n-1$, which is obviously false.